# Export odoo database to sqlite in cronjob

Tags: sqlite, cron, odoo

It is possible to create a cronjob in Odoo to export specific tables of the database to sqlite? I want to create a automated task that takes some specific tables of a module and them export it to a sqlite file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Odoo module

**https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/base_external_dbsource_sqlite/**

Configuration described in module itself.